# awk to Read between two Particular Strings and discard the rest

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm using `awk` to just read text between two strings "Check" and "Result". I've used many variations of it found on the internet and still can't get the favored result. I've tried:

```
awk "/Check:/,/Result:/ {print}"  BMSCA209-040-transfer-report.18-Jun-2014.11:18.csv.tmp | more
```

And I also tried:

```
sed -n "/Check:/,/Result:/p" BMSCA209-040-transfer-report.18-Jun-2014.11:18.csv.tmp | more
```

And still not getting what I want. Each time I get it, this is what I get:

```
ata>    <data fieldName="Timepoint ID" value="B01 SCREENING"/>  <data fieldName="SQCSummary" value=" Nothing Submission Quality and Compliance Report - 201
4-06-03T14:30:00.547-07:00Check: Ensure slice thickness is between 2mm and 5mmResult: FailReason: Image(s) found with slice thickness out of range.   Instanc
e 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.369 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.139541
7628.479.368 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.367 found with slice thickness out
of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.366 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.
55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.365 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.364 found
with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.363 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   I
nstance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.362 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.
1395417628.479.361 found with slice thickness out of range : 1.25   Instance 1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.4094358250.93.1395417628.479.360 found with slice thicknes
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it's better if you post some lines of your input  file...

Comment: I am using command line to output the results before i put it in my script.

Comment: Have you tried `sed` instead ? Something like `sed '1,/Check/d;/Result/,$d'`

Comment: I have tried it but not in the way you suggested. I will give that a shot.

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: Nobody know how your input file is made. You posted only your results, we cannot reconstruct the original file from those. For example can be useful to know if Check and Result are always on the same line or not, if they can be nested...

Comment: @ryekayo - please post the original source material that you're running your `awk` and `sed` commands against.

Comment: I don't have original source material, I typed them in the terminal: `awk "/Check:/,/Result:/ {print}"  BMSCA209-040-transfer-report.18-Jun-2014.11:18.csv.tmp | more` and `sed -n "/Check:/,/Result:/p" BMSCA209-040-transfer-report.18-Jun-2014.11:18.csv.tmp | more`

Comment: His source file is right there in front of us.
The important Parts are "00Check: Ensure slice thickness is between 2mm and 5mmResult: FailReason"

Comment: @polym That is the exact result I am looking for. I tried many different ways in sed and awk and can't come up with the right result

Comment: See my suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for /Check: (.*?)Result:/gs' < file
```

With GNU `grep`, the (almost) equivalent would be:

```
grep -zPo '(?s)Check: \K.*?(?=Result:)' < file
```

Or with `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -Mo1 '(?s)Check: (.*?)Result:' < file
```

Output:

```
Ensure Modality is the same for all images in a DICOM series.
Ensure SeriesDate is in the proper DICOM format (YYYYMMDD) for all images.
[...]
```

Comment: grep seemed to work well on this. I got the results I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

My solution to your problem:

Use `grep` and bash string manipulation like this:

```
RES="$(cat BMSCA209-040-transfer-report.18-Jun-2014.11:18.csv.tmp |  egrep -o 'Check.*Result')"
RES=${RES%Result}
RES=${RES#Check: }
echo $RES
```

Thats it :)

Result is:

```
Ensure slice thickness is between 2mm and 5mm
```

Comment: Ok I get better results. Is there a way to discard anything else found in the text and only leave those lines matching that pattern?

Comment: Doesn't it already discard anything else? Can you post your output? Or do you mean printing out all the Results to a file/tty/shell?

Comment: ue for all images in DICOM series.Result: PassReason: Check: Ensure Modality is the same for all images in a DICOM series.Result: PassReason: Check: Ensure SeriesDate is in the proper DICOM format (YYYYMMDD) for all imagesResult: PassReason: Check: Ensure SeriesDate is the same for all images in a DICOM series.Result: PassReason: Check: Ensure

Comment: I just need everything in betweeen Check and Result, everything else can kick rocks lol

Comment: Are these one line per Check:...Reason:.. pair, or are there multiple instances in one line?

Comment: They appear multiple times throughout the document

Comment: Yes, but do they these pairs appear more than once in one line?

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas did solve your problem properly :)

Comment: i dont think they do appear more than once in the same link

Comment: Haha no probs :), be sure to help people in return ;)

Comment: Will do, im still learning as I go. But glad to help otherwise